# How do I make columns in a table act independently

Tags: spacing, multicolumn

I'd like to make the columns in this table "independent" of each other so they do not create white space if one column has a sentence that is longer than the others'.

The included picture shows the problems, and where I want to move the text to.

[image: How to remove the white space (move the text up)]

The code:

```
\begin{table}[htpb!]
\caption{Byggesystemer}
\label{tab:Byggesystemmer}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\strut
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{3.5cm}@{\hspace{3mm}} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X @{\hspace{3mm}}  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\toprule
 Column 1         & Column 2    & Column 3     \\
\midrule
System 1    &  This piece of text will take up some space and therefore use three whole lines & This could be anything \\
& This could be anything  & How do I remove the white space above this? \\
& This could be anything but fills two lines   &  \\
& This could be anything  & Same problem as above \\
\midrule
System 2                &  This could be anything & This piece of text will take up some space and therefore use more than one line \\
& How to remove white space above this? & This could be anything \\
& This could be anything & Problem again \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: It’s “Fleksibilitet” with “ks” in Danish. Furthermore, it’s “Facadeudformning” in one word. I would also say “ikke-bærende vægge”. `;-)`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Haha, yeah I should've checked the spelling before posting

Comment: I'm afraid I don't speak Danish and hence have no idea what the words in the table mean. Hence a possibly naive question: What's are you trying to show in columns 2 and 3? Do the cells contains ? Please advise.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I tried to make it more obvious now. Hopefuly I succeeded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather the information in columns 2 and 3 is supposed to be displayed as a free-format list. If this assumption is correct, you could achieve your formatting objective by grouping the cells per column. To economize on vertical space, I'd recommend keeping to single-spacing but employing hanging indentation for the list items.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{%
   \RaggedRight\everypar{\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htpb!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5mm}
\caption{Byggesystemmer\strut}
\label{tab:Byggesystemmer}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} lLL @{}}
\toprule
System & Fordele & Ulemper \\
\midrule
Bærende tværvægge &  
  System er hurtigt og let at montere \par
  God lydisolering \par
  Billigere \par
  Oprettelse af ikke bærende vægge &
Begrænset bæredygtighed \\
\midrule
Søjle-plade &  
  Bæredygtighed \par
  Stor planlægningsflexibilitet \par
  Facade udforming &
Dækelementer kan kun optage vandrette kræfter \\
\midrule
Plade-ramme & 
Bæredygtighed \par
  Planlægningsflexibilitet & 
Bjælker er synlige i loftet \\
\midrule
Bærende ydervægge & 
Bæredygtighed \par
  Stor planlægningsflexibilitet \par
  Indre del er rydde & 
Facade er låst \par
  Kan føre til problemer med vinduer  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mico!
I remade your solution a little bit to fit my preference, but it now looks like I wanted it

Comment: @PeterAlbæk - You're most welcome. Just in case it isn't clear: instead of  typing`\par`, one could also insert all-blank lines (since an all-blank line triggers TeX to insert a `\par` token).

Answer (score 1):

Well you *could* use multirows, to fiddle around with your line changes, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htpb!]
    \caption{Byggesystemer}
    \label{tab:Byggesystemmer}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \strut
    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{3.5cm}@{\hspace{3mm}} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X @{\hspace{3mm}}  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
        \toprule
        Column 1         & Column 2    & Column 3     \\
        \midrule
        System 1    &  \multirow{3}{\hsize}{This piece of text will take up some space and therefore use three whole lines} & This could be anything \\
        &                                               & How do I remove the white space above this? \\
        &                                               & Same problem as above \\
        & This could be anything  &  \\
        & This could be anything but fills two lines   &  \\
        & This could be anything  &  \\
        \midrule
        System 2                &  This could be anything & \multirow{3}{\hsize}{This piece of text will take up some space and therefore use more than one line} \\
        & How to remove white space above this? &  \\
        & This could be anything &  \\
        &  & This could be anything \\
        &  & Problem again \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You would probable be better off with just something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htpb!]
    \caption{Byggesystemer}
    \label{tab:Byggesystemmer}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \strut
    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{3.5cm}@{\hspace{3mm}} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X @{\hspace{3mm}}  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
        \toprule
        Column 1         & Column 2    & Column 3     \\
        \midrule
        System 1    &  This piece of text will take up some space and therefore use three whole lines \vskip 1ex   
                       This could be anything \vskip 1ex                                                            
                       This could be anything but fills two lines \vskip 1ex                                        
                       This could be anything                                                                    
                           & This could be anything \vskip 1ex
                             How do I remove the white space above this? \vskip 1ex
                             Same problem as above \\
        \midrule
        System 2                &  This could be anything \vskip 1ex
                                   How to remove white space above this? \vskip 1ex
                                   This could be anything                            
                                       & This piece of text will take up some space and therefore use more than one line \vskip 1ex
                                         This could be anything \vskip 1ex
                                         Problem again \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

### A few notes

Since you are not using your table rows as real rows, you can either try and brute force LaTeX to do what you want it to do (first option), or just give up trying to force your content into rows (second option).

Also, a MWE (Minimal Working Example) is something you can just copy paste into your favourite tex editor and compile to see your output, like the ones I provided. Yours was missing an adequate preamble.

Answer (score 0):

I made a template showing how I made it using @Mico's idea.
I apologize for the danish, but the solution can be seen in the spacing.

[image: Solution image with no white space]

Code:

```
\newcolumntype{L}{>{%
       \RaggedRight\everypar{\hangafter=1}}X}
    \begin{table}[htpb!]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2mm}
    \caption{Irregular columns}
    \label{tab:IrregularColumns}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} lLL @{}}
    \toprule
    Kolonne 1 & Kolonne 2 & Kolonne 3 \\
    \midrule
    Tekst 1 &  
      Længere tekst, som fylder flere linjer, når man skriver noget langt. \par \vspace{2mm}
      Kort tekst \par \vspace{2mm}
      Kort tekst \par \vspace{2mm}
      Mindre kort tekst &
    Kort tekst \par \vspace{2mm}
    Kort tekst \par \vspace{2mm}
    Længere tekst, som fylder flere linjer, når man skriver noget langt \\
    \midrule
    Tekst 2 &  
      Kort tekst \par \vspace{2mm}
      Mindre kort tekst \par \vspace{2mm}
      Længere tekst, som fylder flere linjer, når man skriver noget langt. &
    Her skriver jeg en masse volapyk, fordi jeg skal vise dig det smarte i, at man kan have forskellige længder i sætningerne uden at det ødelægger noget for kolonnen ved siden af. \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
```

- 

Comment: `\hangafter=1` without `\hangindent=1em` (or however deep the hanging indentation is supposed to be) doesn't achieve any useful. If you don't want hanging indentation at all in type-`L` columns, just write `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}`.